# Latex why can't I have bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have a weird problem. I've created a simple document, the structure is pasted below. Initially I never included the bibliography section because it's a book and I don't need it. When I compiled the document, I got an error saying that I don't have a bibliography style so I included one. Then I received an error that there are no citations in document, I've included a bogus citation with `\nocite{}` so it won't show up in the document, if I did that I needed a bib file which I created. The document works now, but I have the Bibliography page at the end and I don't need it.
So my questions are:

- Why can't I have a book type document without bibliography? What do I have to do?
- or alternatively is there a command that doesn't generate the bibliography?

Latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %for headers and footers
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{XXX - Book title - XXX}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{page \thepage}
\rfoot{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\center 
\textsc{\LARGE XXX}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large XXX}\\[0.5cm] 
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
{\large \today}\\[4cm]
\vfill 
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\part{SSS}

\chapter{SSS}
\chapter{SSS}

\nocite{zero}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome. (2) You do not need any bibliography? Exactly which editor are you using? I've seen some that automatically runs bibtex even if the user does not use it.

Comment: What editor do you use? What's the build chain? You should be able to write a document without bibliography without any tricks.

Comment: If you don't need a bibliography, you can remove the `\bibliography{Bib}` line from your document.

Comment: Right. I never thought of that. I was using quick build which I preconfigured to use bib tex. Tx

Comment: Then just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

To not have a bibliography just remove the statement

```
\bibliography{Bib}
```

from your file.